# Envio de caracteres pela porta serial incluindo bytes de valor zero

Tags: c, c++

Estou fazendo uma aplicação na qual preciso enviar via serial para um hardware externo um array de caracteres (declarados como `unsigned char`) que contém comandos e tempos.

Com os comandos não tenho nenhum problema, haja visto que cada comando corresponde a um `unsigned char` ('A','B', etc.). O problema está com o tempo.

O tempo está armazenado em uma variável `unsigned short int` que eu acesso *byte* a *byte* através de um vetor `t` de `unsigned char`, utilizando o seguinte `union`:

```
union tempos {
    unsigned short int tempo; //16 bits ou 2 bytes
    unsigned char t[2]; //8 bits ou 1 byte [cada posição]
}temp;
```

Sendo assim, um exemplo da estrutura do *array* de `unsigned char` que eu devo mandar é o seguinte:

```
[cabeçalho] [comando1] [comando2] [byte1 do tempo1 (temp.t[0])] [byte2 do tempo1 (temp.t[1])] [comando 3]
```

O problema é quando um dos *bytes* de tempo é igual a 0, já que 0 corresponde a `NULL` na tabela ASCII e `NULL` é o caractere que marca o fim de um vetor de `char`. Então quando essa condição ocorre meu *array* não termina de ser formado (por haver um `NULL`) e consequentemente não é transferido corretamente via serial.

---

Editado (acrescentado um comentário importante ao corpo da pergunta):

```c
WriteFile(hComm,Buffer,strlen(Buffer),&bytesEscritos,NULL);
```

O código do envio é esse. `hComm` é a variável de configurações da serial, `Buffer` o array de `unsigned char` que eu quero enviar, o terceiro parâmetro é o tamanho do array, o quarto é o número de bytes escritos e o último é uma configuração de overlapping. O problema é que `Buffer` não possui o valor que deveria devido ao `NULL` correspondente à 0. Por exemplo, ao invés de ter `#ABTTCD@`, onde `A`, `B`, `C` e `D` são comandos e `T` cada um dos bytes de tempo, `Buffer` vale `#ABT` ou `#AB` dependendo de qual dos bytes de tempo vale 0.

Comment: Você não pode configurar para transferir o struct inteiro pelo tamanho sizeof(SeuStruct) ao invés de transferir até o limitador NULL? Se der, posta o código do trecho que você faz a transferência serial, para a gente ver o que você está utilizando e tal.

Comment: Eu não transfiro até o limitador NULL, eu tenho uma variável (chamada Buffer) que armazena o que eu vou enviar pela serial. A colocação indesejada do NULL impede que essa variável Buffer seja formada até o final. É algo como se o "[comando3]" citado na pergunta não fosse incluído devido a presença do NULL.

Comment: Que chamada de função de qual biblioteca você está usando para enviar os bytes? Quais são os seus parâmetros?

Comment: `WriteFile(hComm,Buffer,strlen(Buffer),&bytesEscritos,NULL);` O código do envio é esse. `hComm` é a variável de configurações da serial, `Buffer` o array de unsigned char que eu quero enviar, o terceiro parâmetro é o tamanho do array, o quarto é o número de bytes escritos e o último é uma configuração de overlapping. O problema é que Buffer não possui o valor que deveria devido ao NULL correspondente à 0. Por exemplo, ao invés de ter #ABTTCD@, onde A,B,C e D são comandos e T cada um dos bytes de tempo, Buffer vale #ABT ou #AB dependendo de qual dos bytes de tempo vale 0.

Comment: Há a possibilidade de fazer uma verificação antes de executar o código de envio e, caso algum parâmetro seja null, substituir o seu valor por um válido?

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, mas o problema é na hora de ler esse parâmetro no software que vai receber esse conjunto de bytes. Por exemplo, se eu identificar o valor 0 e substitui-lo por 50 na hora do envio, na hora de receber não tem como eu saber se esse 50 originalmente era um 50 ou um 0. Pensei também em somar 1 em ambos os bytes antes do envio e na hora do recebimento subtrair 1, o que vai falhar na hipótese de um dos bytes (ou ambos) serem iguais a 255.

Comment: Você pode adicionar mais uma variável na função de envio para fazer o controle, ou até mesmo implementar um mecanismo de verificação calculado em ambos os lados com base nos parâmetros pra ter certeza que toda a informação foi enviada e recebida sem perdas. Não é a melhor solução, mas vai funcionar enquanto não descobrir outra forma.

Comment: @ThiagoCavali Acrescentei o seu comentário ao corpo da pergunta, mudei o título e postei uma resposta. Dê uma olhada e diz o que acha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está na instrução que você está usando:

```c
WriteFile(hComm,Buffer,strlen(Buffer),&bytesEscritos,NULL);
```

Observe que o `strlen` vai retornar o tamanho até o primeiro byte com valor zero e é aí que está o seu problema. **Não utilize `strlen` para fazer isso**! Você precisa usar uma outra forma para medir o tamanho do que você quer enviar, algo que consiga aceitar valores 0 dentro do seu `Buffer`.

A forma para medir o tamanho provavelmente consistirá na soma do tamanho de cada um dos termos, aonde um termo pode ser um cabeçalho, um comando ou um elemento do union. Me parece que o cabeçalho e o comando tem sempre o tamanho 1 (`sizeof(unsigned char)`) e o union sempre tem o tamanho 2 (`sizeof(temp)`). Basta somar tudo.

Obviamente, se o que você envia neste ponto sempre está no formato `#ABTTCD@`, aonde `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` e cada um dos `T` tem exatamente um byte, me parece trivial definir que o valor do terceiro parâmetro deveria ser sempre 8.